# How to print the "least" character in a string using only a single loop?

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm trying to print the "least" character in a string, where the a character is smaller if it's closer to the beginning of the alphabet than another character, and it's first index position.
I'm supposed to use only 1 loop to determine the index of the character, and am not allowed to use min, max, index, find, ord, chr, or lists.
For example:

```
leastChar("yRrcDefxBqubSlyjYelskd")
```

should yield:

```
The least char is 'B' and occurs at position 8.
```

Currently I have:

```
def leastChar(inputString):
    lowerString = inputString.lower()
    print(lowerString)
    indexLength = (len(lowerString) - 1)
    print(indexLength)
    index = 0
    for i in range(indexLength):
        if lowerString[i] < lowerString[i+1]:
            index = i
    print("The least char is '{0}' and occurs at position {1}".format(inputString[index], index))
```

Which returns:

```
leastChar("yRrcDefxBqubSlyjYelskd")
yrrcdefxbqubslyjyelskd
21
The least char is 'l' and occurs at position 18
```

I've tried multiple variations, but even using more than 1 loop I find myself getting consistently wrong answers in various positions.
Also, in case it matters, leastChar('blAh') will return 'A' in position 2 like it's supposed to.

The closest I've come to what seems correct, I think, is when I put another for loop inside the initial for loop hoping that I could increment that variable to compare 'i' to it such as:

```
for i in range(indexLength):
    for j in range(indexLength):
        if lowerString[i] < lowerString[j]:
```

And do something with that, but I was unable to make it work.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: ["The simplest case of a selection algorithm is finding the minimum (or maximum) element by iterating through the list, keeping track of the running minimum – the minimum so far – (or maximum)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)

Comment: @melpomene Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @melpomene’s comment, the algorithm <del>trick (or as fancy computer scientists call it, heuristic)</del> is to keep track of **both** the minimum position and minimum value as you are iterating through the string.

```
def leastChar(inputString):
    # handle cases where inputString is `None` or empty
    if not inputString:
        print('Oh no, inputString is blank!  Run away!')
        return
    lowerString = inputString.lower()
    print(lowerString)
    # use enumerate to keep track of the index as
    # you are iterating over a list
    min_value = lowerString[0]
    min_pos = 1
    for index, ch in enumerate(lowerString, 1):
        # check to see if current char is closer to 
        # front of alphabet than our current minimum
        if ch < min_value:
            # if so, keep track of the current pos/value
            # as the new minimum
            min_pos = index
            min_value = ch
            # pythonic: min_pos, min_value = index, ch
    print("The least char is '{0}' and occurs at position {1}".format(min_value, min_pos))
```

Comment: That's not a heuristic, that's an algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I haven't really looked at much about the enumerate function yet so I'll make sure to get familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways:

1) You're not allowed to use  min, max, index, find, ord, chr, or lists?
I would try to work with rfind() or rindex(). :^)

2) Copy your string and use sort() to find the smallest char in your copy. Then you should use search() to return the position of this char in your original InputString.

3) Create an alphabetic string "abcdef...." and build up a complex while-if-try-except construct to get a result, but everyone would hate it. :^)

Comment: Haha, I'm not sure what a try-except construct is(yet) but I imagine it would be incredibly fun for me!